# Jython How to remove characters a string

Tags: python, regex, websphere, jython, wsadmin

This is a WebSphere related question.

I am trying to turn this command into variables

```
AdminConfig.modify('(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1324400045826)'
```

I've found that this command:

```
AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty', 'URL*cam_group*)').splitlines()
```

Will return:

```
['URL(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1324400045826)', 'URL(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1355156316906)']
```

So I turned that command into a variable:

```
j2ee = AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty', 'URL*cam_group*)').splitlines()
```

And i'm able to get the string that I want by typing "j2ee[0]" I get

```
'URL(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1324400045826)'
```

So that is exactly what I wanted, minus the URL part in the front. How can I get rid of those characters?!

Comment: I tried adding the following to search 'm = re.search('?<(URL', 'j2ee[0]')
m.group(0)' and I ran into error 'Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in ?
  File "/opt/websphere/appserver/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib/sre.py", line 57, in search
  File "/opt/websphere/appserver/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib/sre.py", line 136, in _compile
error: nothing to repeat
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirement, but it seems to me that you want to modify some attributes of J2EEResourceProperty object.

If this is the case, then you don't need to remove that "URL" string, actually you shouldn't do that. The string `'URL(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1324400045826)'` fully identifies WebSphere configuration object. Try this:

```
AdminConfig.modify('URL(cells/taspmociias204Cell01/clusters/cam_group|resources.xml#J2EEResourceProperty_1324400045826)', [['value', 'the new value'], ['description', 'the new description']])
```

BTW: you can also try using WDR library (https://github.com/WDR/wdr/). Then your script would look as follows:

```
prop = listConfigObjects('J2EEResourceProperty')[0]
prop.value = 'the new value'
prop.description = 'the new description'
```

Disclosure: I'm one of WDR contributors.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a simple replace regular expression to parse out the URL part.

For example:

```
import re
mystr = 'URL(blahblahblah)'
re.sub(r'^URL', "", mystr)
```

This is a handy tool to learn and test your regular expressions to make sure they are correct.
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/